# Map List of objects to Map by

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I want to group list of users by `id()` using Java Streams.

For example, I have `List: new User(1L, "First"), new User(2L, "Second")`.

How can I group this list to get `Map<Long, User>`?

```
1L -> new User(1L, "First"),
2L -> new User(2L, "Second")
```

**User.java**

```
public final class User {
    final Long id;
    final String name;

    public User(final Long id, final String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String name() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you plan to have multiple users with the same ID and if yes, how would you merge them? take the first/last one in encounter order or collect them to a `List`?

Comment: @Eugene no, the list will contain users with unique ids

Comment: in this case the answer from Eran (or the duplicate) will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each ID is mapped to a single `User`, use `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<Long,User> users = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::id,Function.identity()));
```